# Game Center sandbox on multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am building an app that uses Game Center. To test I was using my iPhone and the simulator to log in with different accounts. I now want to use my wife's phone to test with me and when I open the app it's not logging into the sandbox.

It shows the game enter modal logged in but play now and invite buttons are greyed out and it says unauthenticated user.

How do I make my wife's iphone use Game Center sandbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being that I wasn't opening the modal sandbox sign in from my app. I made a code change that upgraded the call to display the login to support IOS6. The previous method I was using was deprecated. Therefore the new code I put in forgot to present the modal for sign in which left me hanging when I went into the app.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm having this issue and can't find a solution

Comment: i didnt have code to show the sandbox login if a user was not logged in therefore i had no ability to log in if i was logged out.

Comment: Ah. I think I must have been having a different problem, then.

Answer (score 1):

> As a developer, you are required to create a separate Game Center account for Sandbox. At any given time, you must choose whether to log into Sandbox for testing, or into the live environment. Start by launching the Game Center app and **logging out the currently authenticated player**. After this, **run your game or another Game Center-enabled game**. Depending on how that app is distributed, you enter different credentials. If that app is provisioned for development, **enter your test account information (logging you into the Sandbox)**. Otherwise, enter your live account information (logging you into the live environment.

Just log out of Game Center and launch your app. Then you enter you log into your test account.

From [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH17-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

Launch Gamecenter -> Me -> Tap on Account: -> Sign Out. Sign in with your sandbox account.

Comment: Did you set up Game Center on your app in iTunes Connect? You need to that first before anything.

Comment: Yes that is all done and it works fine when I test my game between my iPhone and the iPhone simulator .